# How can I Click angular application button using selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I can Login successfully but There is button "Start new booking" but my script doesn't click that button.

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.ByAngular;
 import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.NgWebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

 public class NewClass {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    NgWebDriver ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
                    ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        driver.get("https://visa.vfsglobal.com/gbr/en/mlt/login");
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click();
                    
                    // Login                     
                    
                    driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-0")).sendKeys("*****@gmail.com");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-1")).sendKeys("password");
                    
                    
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-login/section                /div/div/mat-card/form/button")).click();
                                 
                    driver.findElement(By.className("mat-button-wrapper")).click();
                                    
 }

}
```

Sample Image Here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEv9c.png)

Help me How can i click that button. what is the problem , how can i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try those line . actually working for me

```
Thread.sleep(10000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-dashboard/section/div/div[2]/button")).click();
```

Comment: welcome. Keep posting nice problem.

Comment: without html code, how can you provide xpath ?

Comment: there is website link, inside driver.get(); go to link and inspect you will get xpath code